# How to solve this errors Ant, add platform android and cordova build android failure

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, ant, phonegap-build

1. Here is a **PATH** in environment :

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\work\SDK\SoftPhonegap\ADT\sdk\platform-tools;D:\work\SDK\SoftPhonegap\ADT\sdk\tools;D:\work\SDK\SoftPhonegap\apache-ant-1.9.5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;D:\work\SDK\SoftPhonegap\ADT\sdk\build-tools

A. Error log of **cordova build android**

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\work\SDK\SoftPhonegap\ADT\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:601: The following error oc
curred while executing this line:
D:\work\SDK\SoftPhonegap\ADT\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:542: Unable to resolve proj
ect target 'android-21'

Total time: 0 seconds

D:\work\SDK\SoftPhonegap\ADT\hello\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js
:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "ant debug -f D:\work\SDK\SoftPho
negap\ADT\hello\platforms\android\build.xml -Dout.dir=ant-build -Dgen.absolute.d
ir=ant-gen"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: D:\work\SDK\SoftPhonegap\ADT\hello\p
latforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: D:\work\SDK\SoftPhonegap\ADT\hello\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: C
ommand failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cor
dova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
```

B **Error log of Ant**

```
C:\Users\user>ant
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.
0_45\lib\tools.jar
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

C. when **add platform android**

```
D:\work\SDK\SoftPhonegap\ADT\hello>cordova platform add android
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.7.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.7.2
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms\android
        Package: com.example.hello
        Name: HelloWorld
        Android target: android-21
Copying template files...
Project successfully created.
Installing "com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin" for android
Installing "com.salesforce" for android
Installing "org.apache.cordova.device" for android
Could not run SalesforceMobileSDK plugin android pre-install script
You are running node v0.10.25
You need to be running node 0.12 or above
You won't be able to successfully run: cordova build
Running SalesforceMobileSDK plugin android post-install script
The "android" utility does not exist at D:\work\SDK\SoftPhonegap\ADT\sdk\tools;D
:\work\SDK\SoftPhonegap\ADT\sdk\platform-tools\tools\android.bat.  Make sure you
've properly installed the Android SDK.
```

Comment: Please post the error log

Comment: Now i add error log. Please help to solve  and I tried to solve it 3 days ago.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. Uninstall node v0.10.25
2. install node 0.12 or above
3. remove platform android (cordova platform rm android)
4. add platform android (cordova platform add android)
5. build android (cordova build android)
6. Done

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give platform_tools pah also, you should post your error log,
anyway here is how my PATH looks like

```
C:\Users\amitabhs\AppData\Roaming\npm;F:\Softs\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools;F:\Softs\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools;F:\Softs\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platforms;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.5\bin;
```

check if it helps

Comment: Which plugins have you added to your project till now? I think its a plugin problem.

Comment: Plugins which i add are com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin, com.salesforce and  org.apache.cordova.device. I don't think because of plugins because i dont add plugins it also still can't build android.

Comment: Your error log says "Unable to resolve project target 'android-21'" which means your sdk dont have specific target, do this - after downloading sdk open sdk manager, open it, then download latest android api android-21(5.0 lollipop) and try again. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Compile your project in https://build.phonegap.com/

There you have no problems with OS and can compile for all OS.
I use then for IOS compilation.

Comment: I think i can't use this https://build.phonegap.com/. I try it to download apk file after it built. My project used cordova. It is not Phonegap application